# What degree does someone need to pursue in Germany after finishing an MBBS degree in South Asia?

Tags: germany, medicine

After finishing an [MBBS degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Medicine,_Bachelor_of_Surgery#Pakistan) in South Asia (Pakistan) (a 5-year bachelor's degree plus a 1-year internship in the hospital) what kind of additional courses or degress are necessary to take (in Germany) to become a professional medical doctor in Germany?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the MBBS degree would qualify you to practise medicine in Pakistan. In order to practise medicine in Germany, you need the *approbation*. Depending on where in Germany you want to work, you would apply to a different office to get it. Your application would need to make the case that your MBBS degree is equvialent to having studied in Germany, or that any shortfalls would be compensated for by your work experience. If they aren't convinced, they can make you sit an exam (*Gleichstellungspruefung*). They can also approve or decline your application straight away.

The Marburger Bund (more or less the union for physicians in Germany) provides more detailed information here:

https://www.marburger-bund.de/bundesverband/service/aerztinnen-und-aerzte-mit-auslaendischer-qualifikation/foreign-trained-1-0